How do I connect Traces in Splunk Observability Cloud with Logs using the Splunk Otel Collector
We are using the Splunk Otel Collector for sending logs to Splunk Enterprise and traces to Splunk Observability Cloud. An integration has been made between these two so that logs are accessible in Log Observer.
What I want is to be able to see the logs related to a trace.

Is this possible by only using the collector or do we need to do anything else?
Kinda defeats the whole purpose with the collector if we still need to add code to all of our services.
Our services are .net.
